# How can i update my save image in edit form???

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Database table

Model class

[Whenever i try to submit the form it gives the error something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fWwI.png)

Comment: You need to post your code first

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.file, new {@src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageData,0,Model.ImageData.Length)" ,type="file",style="border-radius:25px;",@class="btn btn-primary"})
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage("CustomError")

Comment: I am trying something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your model for validations. And make javascript validations enable true from web.config. And please post code then we can suggest you better.